# incorrect Boost Log timestamp format

Tags: c++, logging, boost, boost-log

I'm using Boost 1.54 Log and I initialize my logging in the following way:

```
namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace src = boost::log::sources;
namespace expr = boost::log::expressions;
namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;
namespace attrs = boost::log::attributes;
namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;

BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(line_id, "LineID", unsigned int)
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(severity, "Severity", severity_level)
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(tag_attr, "Tag", std::string)
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(timestamp, "TimeStamp", boost::posix_time::ptime)

logging::add_common_attributes();
boost::shared_ptr<logging::core> core = logging::core::get();

// setup console log
logging::add_console_log (
    std::clog,
    keywords::filter = severity >= debug,
    keywords::format = (
        expr::stream << expr::format_date_time(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") <<
            line_id << " [" << severity << "] " << expr::smessage
    )
);
```

and this is a sample of the generated output:

```
2013-09-13 10:17:471 [warn] You are running in debug mode - assertions are enabled.
2013-09-13 10:17:472 [info] loading data completed
2013-09-13 10:17:473 [debug] applying xxx completed
2013-09-13 10:17:474 [debug] computing xxx completed
2013-09-13 10:17:475 [debug] xxx completed
2013-09-13 10:17:476 [info] xxx completed
2013-09-13 10:17:477 [debug] xxx completed
2013-09-13 10:17:478 [debug] computing xxx completed
2013-09-13 10:17:479 [info] testing xxx completed
2013-09-13 10:17:4710 [info] xxx
2013-09-13 10:17:4711 [debug] xxx completed
```

The output seconds of the Timestamp is totally incorrect, but according to Boost Log documentation `%S` is the correct formatting setting for seconds. Would this be a bug?

Comment: Please add included headers to let others use a MWE. I'm stumbled on a `namespace definition not allowed` at `BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(line_id, "LineID", unsigned int)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have a space between the time and the `line_id`, so they run together.

Answer (score 2):

Otherwise replace the keywords::format by following code :

```
 /*< log record format >*/
    keywords::format =
    (
        expr::stream
        //<< std::hex   //To print the LineID in Hexadecimal format
        << std::setw(8) << std::setfill('0') 
        << expr::attr< unsigned int >("LineID")
        << "\t"
        << expr::format_date_time<boost::posix_time::ptime>("TimeStamp","%H:%M:%S.%f")
        << "\t: <" << logging::trivial::severity
        << "> \t" << expr::smessage
    )
```